# on instead of live?

Tags: jquery, live

This might be a simple question but in some cases when I dynamically create elements .on doesn't work but live works.

I know its better to use .on, but what am I doing wrong?

This works for me:

```
    $('.btnMore').live('click', function () {
    // do something
    }
```

This doesn't work for me:

```
    $('.btnMore').on('click', function () {
    // do something

    }
```

How can I make the .on work at all times, like .live?

Comment: When it doesn't work, in what way does it not work?  Is there a console error?  What version of jQuery are you using when this happens?

Comment: Those are not the same.  See the documentation.

Comment: What JQuery version are you using ?

Comment: which version of jquery are you using? looks like very old

Comment: Use live instead of on if that's what you want...

Comment: @AbeMiessler `on` can do everything that `live` can do.

Comment: I use Jquery 2.0.0, but now I figured out the solution. Thanks for all the '-' for the question and no answers.

Comment: Snarkiness will get you nowhere. StackOverflow generally expects you to read the documentation before asking us for help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

This works:

`$(document).on('click', '.btnMore', function () { 
// do something
}`

Comment: Ah, didn't see your solution before posting :)

Answer (score 0):

jquery `on` method works since jquery version 1.7 see `on` [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 0):

See this [blog](http://www.jquery4u.com/jquery-functions/on-vs-live-review/#.UEbZwIogdRM) for the differences between .on() and .live()

but it looks like instead of

```
$('selector').live(event, function(){ //do stuff here })
```

you want

```
$('selector').live(event, function(){ //do stuff here })
```